# How to detect when an element comes in view of another element ie Modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've seen tutorials that demonstrates how to do this but all that I've seen uses "window" or examples where the element comes in view from the bottom of a page. I have a modal with a fixed height that scrolls:

```
const ItemMarkup = forwardRef(({user}, ref) => <li ref={ref}>...</li>)

// This opens up in a modal: https://headlessui.dev/react/dialog
<div className="content">
  {/** Tailwind's fixed height 'h-96' */}
  <ul ref={scrollRef} className="h-96 overflow-scroll">
    {users.map((user, index) => 
      <ItemMarkup
        {/** I'm looking for the last item/element to come in this view (ul) */}
        ref={users.length === index + 1 ? ref : null}
        key={user.id} 
        user={user} 
      />
    )}
  </ul>
</div>
```

I've looked at this [demo](https://usehooks.com/useOnScreen/) but again, it's for the entire page/window. Then I've tried using this function:

```js
// element would be the ref.current
// target would be scrollRef
// But this always return false
function isInViewport(element, target) {
  const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (
      rect.top >= 0 &&
      rect.left >= 0 &&
      rect.bottom <= target.innerHeight &&
      rect.right <= target.innerWidth
  );
}
```

Here's how I tried the attempt:

```js
const ref = useRef()
const scrollRef = useRef()

// From the demo link above
const onScreen = useOnScreen(ref)

// No idea if I need this
const [scrolling, setScrolling] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
  const onScroll = e => {
    setScrolling(true)
    console.log(isInViewport(ref.current, scrollRef))
  };
  scrollRef?.current.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
  //console.log(ref, onScreen)

  return () => scrollRef?.current.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
}, [ref, onScreen, scrolling])
```

This seems all wrong. Is there a react hook I could to determine when a specific element comes in a modal view or any scrollable view that I specify and not the document view? I just cannot find any documentation/tutorials on this.

I'm creating an infinite scroll. When the last items comes in view, of the modal, I then trigger a function to fetch more data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I have over complicated things:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const onScroll = e => {
    console.log(isInViewport(e.target))
  };
  scrollRef?.current.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);

  return () => scrollRef?.current.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
}, [])


function isInViewport(element) {
  return element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop === element.clientHeight
}
```

Now when I scroll to the bottom, I see a console log of `true`.